# Docker compose - installing new npm packages on nodejs running container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I love working with Docker compose to run a NodeJS container alongside Postgres and Redis containers. The developer experience is great... except when you're downloading new npm packages on the fly as you're working on the NodeJS code. Let me explain:

Here's an example Dockerfile for the NodeJS image (just focused on local development, not a production optimized option for this example)

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node

###################
# Other multi-stage builds for production, not relevant to this post
```

And then here's a Docker compose file which uses this image:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - ./usr/src/app/node_modules 
    env_file:
    - .env
    command: npm run start:dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

As mentioned above, this all works great and my local server is now spun up in a Docker container.

But let's say I install a new npm package in the NodeJs project while the containers are running, and then use this package in my code.

The Docker container logs will then throw an error because the package has installed on my local node_modules folder, but the node_modules folder in the Docker container is now out of date.

I have to run the following commands to get the Docker container to get it working again:

```
docker compose down
docker compose up -d --build
```

This is a bit painful and takes a while to rebuild the image every time - especially compared to working with a local server run on a machine (with npm run dev, for example) where you don't even need to restart the server after a new package install - it just works!

Does anyone have any suggestions to improve the above workflow and improve the developer experience?

Comment: Can you use Node directly on the host, without Docker?  If you have other dependencies like databases in the Compose file it could make sense to launch those dependencies in containers, but Docker is designed so that normally a container can't access host files at all and you need to go out of your way to get around that.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes defo. I could just run `npm run dev` on the host for the nodejs app and run the other dependencies (e.g. Postgres & Redis) in Docker compose - this setup works with no issues. The upside though of having the NodeJS app as a running container is that it closely resembles the production environment. Plus it's also a bit simpler dev experience to just run 1 command (`docker compose up`) instead of 2 commands (`docker compose up` and `npm run dev`)